# Protect wp-login, but get an internal server error

Tags: htaccess

I am trying to protect my wp-login by

```
#Protect wp-login
<Files wp-login.php>
AuthUserFile ~/.htpasswd
AuthName "Private access"
AuthType Basic
require user myusername
</Files>
```

after the password protect I get a 500 internal server error and not the wp-admin

How can I fix this? 
And how can I logout and try again to see if it works??

ps: source from [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have edited your .htaccess file in Windows notepad or text editor.
If you did use Windows text editor then it must have added some special chars in .htaccess file and that will lead to 500 internal server error. Never edit in Windows text editor.

Use notepad++ for editing .htaccess and .htpasswd files.

Answer (score 0):

### Adding a line in HTACCESS file

You proceeding is good, but should add an extra line of code that should go in the first line of your `.htaccess` file from the root directory of your wordpress installation:

> `ErrorDocument 401 default`

This will avoid your error.

I would strongly recommend to protect your site's admin this way. The entire explanation and instructions can be found in [this website](https://cybmeta.com/htaccess-proteger-con-contrasena-wplogin-y-wp-admin) but it's in Spanish.